# How to generate uuid3 or uuid5 in spark/databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, uuid

What is the preferred (i.e. performant) method to generate UUID3 (or uuid5) strings in an Apache Spark context? In particular, this is within a pyspark structured streaming job, though alternatives to that could be entertained if needs be.

So far I've been able to generate UUIDs with the [databricks runtime's builtin method](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/uuid.html), but it only provides the UUID4 (?), random version. I now have a use-case where I want to be able to consistently generate the same UUID from a given `(namespace, name)` pair, which is conveniently [supported by python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid3).

Is doing this with a pandas UDF likely the best bet? How should I think about the options here. I'd like to balance introducing new components with performance, so something like a Scala UDF seems like a last resort at this point.